# inserting a function call after the current instruction using LLVM

Tags: load, llvm, instructions

I want to insert a function call in my code after the current instruction using LLVM. The function call takes as arguments a load instruction and I also want this load instruction to load the value after the current instruction is executed. If I create load instruction as

```
new loadinst(*ptr, name, current_instruction)
```

it loads the value of the ptr before the current_instruction is executed. Help needed.

Answer (score 0):

To create new function calls, use `CallInst::Create`. You can find plenty examples of using it in the LLVM code base. It takes an array of arguments, one of which can be the `Value*` representing a `load` instruction (or anything, really).

One good example to look at is `examples/Fibonacci/fibonacci.cpp`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I already know how to create the function calls. I am doing it using IR Builder. The only problem I had was to set the location of the new instruction. I have got it working now.

Comment: @Mahwish Why not sharing your answer in this thread so other users can benefit from your efforts too.